# Laravel 7 Authentication Check user status in other tables

Tags: laravel

I have three tables:

**users**

```
id
name
email
password
status
```

**companies**

```
id
name
status
```

**users_companies**

```
id
users_id
companies_id
default
status
```

At the time of logging in, I want to verify that the status of all the tables where the user refers, is equal to 1.

is there a way to join the tables when logging in?

how could I issue a custom message if any of the tables has the status of 0. and not only show: **these credentials do not match our records.**

Comment: Join those 3 table with condition status!=1, if there exists any rows then return error.
if you want to override laravel's authentication check, you may have to modify LoginController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your model name for `companies` table is `Company` and model name for `users_companies` table is `UserCompany`.

You have to override `credentials` and `authenticated` methods in `LoginController`

First, check users status is true

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $credentials['status'] = true;
    return $credentials;
}
```

After that, check `UserCompany` and `Company` status is true. If any of them is not true then logout and redirect to the login page showing an error message.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $userCompany = UserCompany::where('users_id', $user->id)->first();
    $company = Company::find($userCompany->companies_id);
    if (!$userCompany->status || !$company->status) {
        $this->logout($request);
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `LoginController` that uses `AuthenticatesUser` trait, create this method in your LoginController to override the default:

```
 /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }
```

Do your extra logic in the method

Comment: but that function is executed when the user has already logged in, right? it would not be correct to check the other tables, before that.

Comment: Yes, the function executes after user is logged in. You can add your check there and if the check fails, simply log the user out. The user won't notice they were ever logged in cos it executes before returning response to user after submitting login data